# What causes error "expected a string literal, but found a user-defined string literal instead" when using 'extern "C"'?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-10

I have code that contains these declarations:

```
class IRealNetDll;

extern "C"__declspec(dllexport)
IRealNetDll * CreateRealInstance(int ilicence);
```

This builds properly with Visual Studio 2012 on Win7.

But on VS 2015, 2017 on Windows 10, this line:

```
extern "C"__declspec(dllexport)
```

results in:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C3690: expected a string literal, but found a user-defined string literal instead
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'IRealNetDll'
```

Why do I get this error, why only on the newer compiler, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but symbols starting with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter (like e.g. `_IRealNetDll`) are reserved everywhere. See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for more information

Comment: Be careful about your spacing (or rather the *lack* of space between things).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The error is *very* related to the `extern "C"__declspec(dllexport)` part. It's the "user-defined string literal" part of the error message that gives it away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When user-defined literals were introduced, it caused a small, breaking change to the language.  String literals now need to be separated from a following identifier by whitespace, otherwise the the identifier is parsed as a user-defined literal operator:

- ```
  "C"__declspec
  ```

  One token, understood as a user-defined literal using the `__declspec` conversion.
- ```
  "C" __declspec
  ```

  Two tokens - the string literal `"C"` and the identifier `__declspec`.

You need to add a space to separate your tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
extern "C"__declspec(dllexport)
IRealNetDll * CreateRealInstance(int ilicence);
```

you should write

```
extern "C"
{
__declspec(dllexport) IRealNetDll * CreateRealInstance(int ilicence);
}
```

Comment: While your proposed solution should work, it's not because of the curly braces `{}`. There is an even simpler solution.

Comment: You are right I think the issue is that a space is missing after "C". But I believe using extern "C" without the curly braces is confusing